# flutter delete database without uninstall app

Tags: flutter, sqlite

We are testing our app and only one sqlite version. Because we don't want to upgrade the db before go live. During testing, we release few stable version to production whether google will accept or reject. Google accepted and now we realised that more than 1000 app downloaded.

But our testing is not done yet and we asked the user to manually uninstall. Now we don't know which version they start downloaded.

So without uninstall the app, their db is not latest and will error occurred.

So this coming release, we want to force delete their database and create latest db schemes. For subsequence release, if we need to change we will create new version of database with onUpdate.

Is there any better way to do so?

Comment: if you're using `sqflite`, see https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/migration_example.md

Comment: Yes, I simply check the old version and drop the table and call initDB function again. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
  Future<String> deleteDbCreateDbDirectory() async {
    final databasePath = await getDatabasesPath();
    final path = join(databasePath, "you_db_name");

    // make sure the folder exists
    // ignore: avoid_slow_async_io
    if (await Directory(dirname(path)).exists()) {
      await deleteDatabase(path);
      await File(path).delete();
    } else {
      try {
        await Directory(dirname(path)).create(recursive: true);
      } catch (e) {
        // ignore: avoid_print
        //print(e);
      }
    }
    ////print("path: $path");
    return path;
  }
```

**Based on sqlite**

Answer (score 0):

**I think this code will help you**

```
 void _createTableCompanyV2(Batch batch) {
      batch.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Company');
      batch.execute('''CREATE TABLE Company (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        name TEXT,
        description TEXT
    )''');
    }
```

[reference link](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/migration_example.md)